# ES5 compatible Object.observe / Object.watch style approach

Tags: javascript

I could do with a way to check if a model has changed, and I thought `Object.observe` was ES6 but from what I can tell its been moved to ES7 but it didn't seem like it has a promising future ahead.

So is there any currently a way to monitor an object and be notified of its changes? I am aware of [WatchJS](https://github.com/melanke/Watch.JS) which is ok but are there any alternatives?

-- Edit --

Just to clear up some confusion, in this scenario this code does not control the model. There is a bit of functionality which basically acts as a validation style system which needs to be notified on model changes to do some processing, so the model knows nothing about this, it is just passed to a class which basically knows what to listen for on a model and get on with it, very much like most MVVM frameworks validaiton systems, however this is not tied to any individual MVVM system.

Comment: I think you're looking for reactive JS: [rxJS](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS)

Comment: The scenario is validation related, so you want to know when a model has updated so you can trigger some form of validation/processing associated with that property. Almost all MVVM frameworks use this sort of approach so its a perfectly fine thing to do, its just there doesn't seem to be many "isolated" ways to achieve this.

Comment: You can always implement the observer pattern into your model yourself.

Comment: @ssube I was going to look at observables but most of them were fairly heavy weight and I just wanted something small which just basically replicated the `Object.observe` functionality.

Comment: https://github.com/polymer/observe-js should be the polyfill you are looking for. Object.observe is withdrawn from the proposal though. You should use Poxies instead.

Comment: In fact it's been moved to ES8.

Comment: Yeah it makes alarm bells ring if its constantly being bumped up to other specifications. I will look into Proxies as I don't really mind how it works I just want a lightweight way to find out if something changes and trigger something, so proxying may solve the problem.